# thousands Operator in highcharts

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts

am trying to as thousand operator in highcharts with Angular js.

I have called set options before calling the charts :

```
Highcharts.setOptions({
        lang: {
            decimalPoint : '.',
            thousandsSep: ','
         }
        });
```

And then when I define thousand operator as `this.{points[0].y:,.0f}` in the following code it is showing me `"Unexpected Expression { and injector " and [$injector:unpr] unresolved dependencies error`.

```
tooltip: {
        style: {
            fontFamily: 'Roboto',
            fontSize: '12px'
        },
        formatter: function () {
            var headerFormat = '<span style="color: #000">Date: <b>' + Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y-%m-%d', new Date(this.x)) + '</b></span><br/>';
            var seriesOneLine = '<span style="color:' + this.points[0].color + '">\u25CF</span> ' + this.points[0].series.name + ': <b>' + this.{points[0].y:,.0f}+ '</b><br/>';
            var seriesTwoLine = '<span style="color:' + this.points[1].color + '">\u25CF</span> ' + this.points[1].series.name + ': <b>' + Math.round(this.points[1].y) + '</b><br/>';
            var seriesThreeLine = '<span style="color:' + this.points[2].color + '">\u25CF</span> Threshold %: <b>'+this.points[2].point.data.alertThresholdPercentage.toFixed(2)+'%</b><br/>';
            return headerFormat + seriesOneLine + seriesTwoLine + seriesThreeLine;
        }
    }
},
```

Any pointer for solution would be very helpful.

Comment: Please add verifiable example . Starting sample can be https://jsfiddle.net/0mdzwb0j/

Answer (score 1):

for thousand separate you can use like this format

```
formatter: function () {
      return '<b>' + this.series.name + ': ' + Highcharts.numberFormat((this.y.toFixed(2) / 1000), 0, '.') + 'k';
                       }
```